# MS-7360 cannot overclock - strangely reboots

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

I've got this motherboard, one HDD on Sata and 4300e dual core CPU.

I have two PSUs: one ~400W (unsure exactly) and one 300W. The biggest problems I encountered so far are problems with overclocking and plugging new graphics card.

After I overclock the CPU, the PC usually reboots several times, eventually it'll come to the safe values. I could overclock my processor without problems on another motherboard, but that time 400W PSU was surely working.

Sometimes it turns on and no monitor output is produced and stays in this state forever (I turn it off eventually). If I install a graphics card my computer reboots a few times before it gets to work.

Do you think it's my Motherboard's fault or maybe the PSUs are insufficent?

Comment: Maybe it's because you're overclocking? A 3GHz CPU is a 3.2GHz CPU that failed 3.2GHz testing.

Comment: I tried to overclock it to 2.4 GHZ from 1.8. I had tested it on other one and was working on 3.4 frequency. Yup, it's obviously overclocking. Butr how can u explain that changing graphics card on standard clocking states make it rebootfew times?